# Resizing variables to improve decompilation results

Tags: decompilation, ghidra

Consider the following, relatively commonplace decompilation misinterpretation, where variable sizes (not just types) are incorrectly guessed, causing suboptimal results:

[image: A double variable being interpreted as 2 4-byte uints]

As you can see, we have what should be a single `double` variable being interpreted as 2 `unsigned int`. In this case, retyping doesn't work, either not doing anything at all, or failing to the usual resizing error:

[image: Variable resizing error]

This, of course, will have ugly side-effects throughout all the remaining decompilation:

[image: Concatenating 2 uints to recover the original double]

Or consider this other example, this time with a stack variable:

[image: A 16-byte stack variable being split into 4 4-byte chunks]

This time, retyping to `uint[4]` or `double[2]` somewhat improves the result, at least merging the variables into one, since we're not changing the size (*16-bytes*), although it still looks suboptimal:

[image: Suboptimal retypings of the above variable]

Ideally, with `double[2]`, this should be separated into 2 single lines, not 4, and without those suffixes. Even better would be to have 2 separate `double`, rather than an array, but retyping won't allow that. It feels like, despite retyping, the original chunk sizes remain constant.

My general questions are:

- Is it possible to fix the variable types **and** sizes better than what the standard retyping method (which sometimes doesn't even work, and some other times produces suboptimal decompilation results) allows one to?
- Can this be done with both stack/memory and register variables? And if so, how?

I'm aware it might require more than what the GUI enables the user to do, such as scripting, that's perfectly fine.

Comment: please do not post pictures of text ... post the text instead, so that everybody can read it ... https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode